# function driver.delete_all_cookies() in selenium python doesn't delete all cookies

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to delete all cookies from browser and then checking that no cookies remained. after that I ran my code I saw that still, some cookies remained... what's the problem? thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 
"C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.walla.co.il")
driver.delete_all_cookies()
lst = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in lst:
    print(cookie)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is more related to the load time from the website.
I just try your code adding a time.sleep(5) and the cookies are deleted correctly.
Probably when you are trying to delete the cookies the page hasn't finished loading