# Keep loop running after closing web browser in selenium

Tags: loops, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver for Chrome. I would like to run a loop on variables in a list but to close the browser and then restart it. (I've got more functions that I call so this is condensed version)

Is there way of continuing the loop, after closing the webdriver down and then restarting it with the driver.get() function? I am closing the complete browser down as I want to eliminate cookies generated after each cycle of the loop. From what I've tried, it seems that `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` just terminates the loop at the first iteration.

Thanks!

```
list = ['apples', 'bananas']

for z in list:
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/'+ z)
    driver.get(z)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone also wanted an answer to this, I've found the following which might help:

- [How to restart Selenium browser after quit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213708/how-to-restart-selenium-browser-after-quit)
- [function driver.delete_all_cookies() in selenium python doesn't delete all cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515085/function-driver-delete-all-cookies-in-selenium-python-doesnt-delete-all-cooki/56527310)

Thanks!